# Can an indexed view be created on system tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Why can't indexed views be created with `sys.` tables?

I don't want to write `order by` every time I have to query this view, so I wanted to create a clustered index on the fields I want to be ordered by.

This is the view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[sysVW_Row_Groups]
--WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(rg.OBJECT_ID) as table_name
    ,i.name as index_name
    --,i.type_desc as index_type_desc

    ,rg.partition_number
    ,p.rows as rows_per_partition_number
    --,p.data_compression_desc as data_compresion_partition
    ,row_group_id
    ,state_description
    ,total_rows as total_rows_row_group
    ,convert(decimal(10,2),(total_rows*1.0/POWER(2,20))*100) as full_row_groups
    --,size_in_bytes
    ,convert(decimal(10,2),(size_in_bytes*1.0)/POWER(2,20)) as size_in_Mbytes 
    ,convert(decimal(10,2),(total_rows*1.0/p.rows)*100) as partition_percentage_rows

    ,deleted_rows
    ,i.compression_delay

    ,ps.name as partition_scheme_name
    --,ps.type_desc as partition_scheme_type_desc

    ,pf.name as partition_function_name
    --,pf.type_desc as partition_function_type_desc
    ,pf.boundary_value_on_right
    ,pf.fanout as number_of_resulting_partitions

FROM SYS.COLUMN_STORE_ROW_GROUPS rg
    inner join sys.partitions p ON rg.partition_number = p.partition_number and object_name(rg.object_id) = object_name(p.object_id) 
            and data_compression_desc = 'COLUMNSTORE' --Focused on in columnstore indexes
    inner join sys.indexes i ON OBJECT_NAME(rg.OBJECT_ID) = OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) 
    inner join sys.partition_schemes ps ON i.data_space_id = ps.data_space_id
    inner join sys.partition_functions pf ON ps.function_id = pf.function_id
```

I know this would help me little on columnstore indexes, but anyway...

I got the following error message:

```
Msg 2720, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sysVW_Row_Groups, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 6]
Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.sysVW_Row_Groups' because it references system object 'SYS.COLUMN_STORE_ROW_GROUPS'.
```

Comment: *"I don't want to write `order by` every time I have to query this view, so I wanted to create a clustered index on the fields I want to be ordered by."* But adding a `CLUSTERED INDEX` to something doesn't force the information returned to be order the same way **every** time a query is run. I have plenty of tables that have a `CLUSTERED INDEX`, however, a `SELECT TOP 10 * ...` will return different results every time. `ORDER BY` and **only** `ORDER BY` can guarentee that. I don't mean to be rude, but this just seems like you're looking for a "excuse" to not write "`ORDER BY {Columns}`".

Comment: @Larnu it's okay! But `clustered index` orders the view in this case, then when the view is quieried records are returned in such an order, am I wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you put that query in a stored procedure and execute the stored procedure to return the results you want?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf yes I can thanks! So sorry, but I am curious why `sys.` tables cannot be schema bound?

Comment: @SNR no it doesn't order the output. Think about this for a second. What happens if you have two views that are somehow ordered and that order conflicts with the second view? There is 1 and ONLY 1 way to order results consistently. That is using an order by statement. You seem to be falling victim to the common fallacy that a clustered index indicates order for a select statement.

Comment: Yes @SNR , you are wrong. Nothing, other than an `ORDER BY` **guarentees** the order rows are returned from query. A `CLUSTERED INDEX` does not guarantee this. It might create the "illusion" that they are in solitude (and even then it's still no guarenteed), but it is far from reliable.

Comment: @SeanLange gives a great example there. Then you also have things like queries that require multiple cores and parallel processing. Some of the rows that are "later" in the sort order may have their processing completed first, which ***might*** result in them being returned in the output before the earlier rows. There are so many variables that effect the order that rows are returned in a query without a `ORDER BY`, and (not) having a `CLUSTERED INDEX` is just a one variable in that.

Comment: @Larnu - Conor Cunningham who answered below has (perhaps had now) a great blog on MSDN demonstrating the fallacy of clustered index ordering with great explanations and examples that prove that it will in fact return rows in strange order eventually.

Comment: How about `unique clustered index`? It is also the same fallacy to claim that rows would be returned in the order they are stored in the index. Can we force index seek to ensure certain order?

Comment: No. The same logical issues would exist. Both multiple tables/views and parallelism. The only way to ensure order of rows is to use an order by clause. Anything else is coincidence and will break at some point.

Comment: @SeanLange & @Larnu okay! Thanks I see the distinction between output and internal computation and since querying an index/view/table doesn't call the `order by` operator in the query plan I think I get it. Thanks a lot!!! It's not a safe way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select * from indexed_view` does not guarantee anything about order returned from a query.  (as the comment suggests).  So, please don't assume that or your application can break.

As to the "why can't you create an indexed view on system tables?" there are a couple of reasons for this.

1. You can create constraints on indexed views which would cause certain system DDL commands to fail (which you would not want a normal user to be able to do).
2. The system tables are actually views themselves.  There are different underlying tables and they are not directly exposed (though you can see them in showplan).  So, we don't let you bind to the internal tables.  While uncommon, SQL can sometimes change these views (on major version upgrade) in ways that could break any indexed views created previously
3. Finally, there is a very different code path to implement how system tables (views) get updated.  It's not using the normal update statements.  There's lots of special logic for locks, latches, maintaining system caches and so on.  So, the logic to maintain indexed views would not work on these objects.  [All of this was done long ago in the name of performance/scale]

Comment: I was going to link to your awesome seatbelt article but it seems your blog on MSDN is gone. That stinks because I have linked to that seatbelt article dozens if not hundreds of times over the last decade since you wrote it.

Comment: Yeah they did a purge of old blogs recently.  I will go see if we can pull that back

Comment: You have several other great posts but that one I have referred others to time and time again.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT I was pretty convinced by 2. Since is one of the restrictions documentation mention. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SeanLange can you please mail me the links you want brought back?  Thx

Comment: I can't find any of your blog posts that exist anymore and not sure how to mail you something. Here is the seatbelt link. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: But there are so many other good posts on your blog, it really is a shame they took them all down.

Comment: FYI we got these "fixed".  You should be able to search for most of these old posts now (hosted on a different spot, but still all there)